# Oracle: Create a table copy exempting totally null rows

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, null, rdbms

I've been tasked with fixing a bad data problem in Oracle.  There are completely null rows (Millions), no PK, no indeces, and the table is used often.  This is causing massive slowdowns in the consuming applications. My thought, since the table also needs to be backed up, is to use the functionality described here: [create full copy of existing table in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696792/create-full-copy-of-existing-table-in-oracle) .  This would give me a fresh table to work with in creating the PK and indeces and insure all triggers and such carry over.  Then I can use renaming to just swap which table is the "backup" versus the one in production.

My thought was to hijack the`WHERE` clause when creating the new table and replace the "WHERE 1 = 0" with a value that filters the totally null rows.  However, by totally null, I mean every value is null.

```
CREATE TABLE 'TABLE' AS SELECT * FROM OLD_TABLE WHERE......
```

Is there  a faster way I can do this than comparing each and every column to the same `SELECT` subquery over and over with `AND`? There's around 60 columns.

```
...WHERE col1 NOT IN (long subquery)
AND col2 NOT IN (identical long subquery)
AND col3 not in....
```

Comment: Don't use subqueries.. just a normal WHERE clause... but you will have to list every column in one way or another to test them all.

Comment: By the way, you should consider using a move rather than a redefinition or CTAS/rename. E.g. `ALTER TABLE old_table MOVE INCLUDING ROWS WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL OR col1 IS NOT NULL OR...`   as for assembling your list of 60 columns, simply script them out by querying `column_name` from `all_tab_columns` in `column_id` order and copy-paste into a notepad editor and shape it up the way you need. There's no need to type it all in.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT *
FROM  old_table
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
OR    col2 IS NOT NULL
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have table with that many rows nor columns, so this is just a theory as I have no idea how would that perform.

---

If you don't want to backup rows where all columns are `null` (by the way, how could you have a primary key in such a table? Primary keys don't allow nulls), why do you need such a complex `where` clause? If you want to skip all nulls, do exactly that.

For example, this is "original" table you have; note the last row whose all columns are null:

```
    SQL> desc test
     Name                                      Null?    Type
     ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
     COL1                                               NUMBER
     COL2                                               CHAR(1)
     COL3                                               NUMBER
    
    SQL> select rowid, t.* from test t;
    
    ROWID                    COL1 COL2       COL3
    ------------------ ---------- ---- ----------
    AAAZNlAAMAAAAOLAAA          1 A
    AAAZNlAAMAAAAOLAAB                        100
    AAAZNlAAMAAAAOLAAC                               --> all NULLs here
```

One option is to use `coalesce` function: if it returns `null`, it means that all columns are null:

```
SQL> create table test_new as
  2  select *
  3  from test
  4  where coalesce(to_char(col1), col2, to_char(col3)) is not null;

Table created.

SQL> select t.rowid, t.* from test_new t;

ROWID                    COL1 COL2       COL3
------------------ ---------- ---- ----------
AAAZNqAAMAAAAOrAAA          1 A
AAAZNqAAMAAAAOrAAB                        100
```

Another option is to specify all columns in `where` clause, one-by-one:

```
SQL> create table test_new_2 as
  2  select *
  3  from test
  4  where col1 is not null
  5     or col2 is not null
  6     or col3 is not null;

Table created.

SQL> select t.rowid, t.* From test_new_2 t;

ROWID                    COL1 COL2       COL3
------------------ ---------- ---- ----------
AAAZNrAAMAAAAOzAAA          1 A
AAAZNrAAMAAAAOzAAB                        100

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use Data Pump export and import utilities by including `where` clause to filter out rows with all nulls.

Comment: To answer your question; the table has no PK and was using another table's reference to a "master" to fetch data.  Naturally, it's a laggy, screwed up nightmare.  It has the feel of someone taking MS Access data and just hurling it in.

Comment: I see; well, did you manage to do what you needed to do?